# Heroku assets:clean is removing application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

The only js file not working on my heroku rails app is application.js

Upon inspecting the push to heroku, I came across this section:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2016-09-14T00:37:23.133498 #268]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5aae0a7515cee878ad1672e486f7fc00/public/assets/application-118acbccb6dea8c49fd5ae3c19a2bf2e1717824c1400b9f4c9a6261d195097c1.js
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (5.94s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:        I, [2016-09-14T00:37:25.328060 #274]  INFO -- : Removed application-bddaccef4e0926301a36a29697beb70a246688b8b43367d159738613d8a5d8ea.js
```

Why is it removing the application.js file?

Comment: rake assets:clean   Removes compiled assets.  Is that the only compiled asset in your application?  Are you using a require_tree directive?  Make sure you have the 12_factor gem from heroku installed for handling assets with their setup.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I deleted the whole public/assets file, and then ran assets:clean, so no I don't think application.js compiled. I have gem `rails_12factor` in my gemfile, and my application.js has `//= require_tree .`

Comment: Did you run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=prodcution" before committing to git and then pushing to heroku?

Comment: @bkunzi01  The point of deleting the public/assets folder was so that heroku would precompile itself. Which it does, but then it deletes the application.js file right afterwards, when it runs assets:clean. And to expand on that, I was having issues precompiling locally due to an error saying 'KeyError: key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME"' after I installed s3, but heroku already is configured, and it's working fine. So the issue is precompiling locally v having heroku do it when i push